# Unable to start activity component info Null Pointer Exception ProgressDialog

Tags: android

I'm getting this Null Pointer exception. Every thread on here I find it has to do with xml objects but mine is crashing on anything to do with Progress Dialog.  Here is the code

```
 public class ActivityCommissions extends Activity {
ProgressDialog pdialog;
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
ListView list;
public CommissionsAdapter adapter;
EditText editsearch;
private ImageView refresh;
static ArrayList<Commission> arraylist = new ArrayList<Commission>();

String pageToken;
GPSTracker gpstracker;
static double latitude, longitude;

ConnectionDetector cd;

 }
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.commissions);
    /* DO IRRELEVANT STUFF */
    search();
}
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
private void Search() {
    //CLEAR SEARCH RESULTS
    arraylist.clear();

    /* CRASHES HERE */
    pdialog = ProgressDialog.show(this.getParent(), "", "Retrieving Commissions...");

    /* INTIALIZE REQUEST QUEUE */
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    /* latitude && longitude */
    latitude = gpstracker.getLatitude();
    longitude = gpstracker.getLongitude();

    /* MORE IRRELEVANT STUFF */
 }
```

It crashes on the line that reads

```
 pdialog = ProgressDialog.show(this.getParent(), "", "Retrieving Commissions...");
```

Here is the error log

```
08-01 12:37:19.626: W/dalvikvm(19602): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ab0a08)
08-01 12:37:19.636: E/AndroidRuntime(19602): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 12:37:19.636: E/AndroidRuntime(19602): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.appusa1/com.appusa1.ActivityCommissions}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-01 12:37:19.636: E/AndroidRuntime(19602):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2225)
08-01 12:37:19.636: E/AndroidRuntime(19602):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2260)
08-01 12:37:19.636: E/AndroidRuntime(19602):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
08-01 12:37:19.636: E/AndroidRuntime(19602):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
08-01 12:37:19.636: E/AndroidRuntime(19602):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-01 12:37:19.636: E/AndroidRuntime(19602):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
08-01 12:37:19.636: E/AndroidRuntime(19602):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
08-01 12:37:19.636: E/AndroidRuntime(19602):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 12:37:19.636: E/AndroidRuntime(19602):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-01 12:37:19.636: E/AndroidRuntime(19602):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-01 12:37:19.636: E/AndroidRuntime(19602):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-01 12:37:19.636: E/AndroidRuntime(19602):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-01 12:37:19.636: E/AndroidRuntime(19602): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-01 12:37:19.636: E/AndroidRuntime(19602):    at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:142)
08-01 12:37:19.636: E/AndroidRuntime(19602):    at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:98)
08-01 12:37:19.636: E/AndroidRuntime(19602):    at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:77)
08-01 12:37:19.636: E/AndroidRuntime(19602):    at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:110)
08-01 12:37:19.636: E/AndroidRuntime(19602):    at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
08-01 12:37:19.636: E/AndroidRuntime(19602):    at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:94)
08-01 12:37:19.636: E/AndroidRuntime(19602):    at com.appusa1.ActivityCommissions.Search(ActivityCommissions.java:127)
08-01 12:37:19.636: E/AndroidRuntime(19602):    at com.appusa1.ActivityCommissions.onCreate(ActivityCommissions.java:87)
08-01 12:37:19.636: E/AndroidRuntime(19602):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4543)
08-01 12:37:19.636: E/AndroidRuntime(19602):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
08-01 12:37:19.636: E/AndroidRuntime(19602):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2181)
08-01 12:37:19.636: E/AndroidRuntime(19602):    ... 11 more
```

Any idea why it's crashing on pdialog? Any help is greatly appreciated. And yes I have imported the ProgressDialog class

Comment: pdialog never its initialised thats why you get null

Comment: Use your context instead of `this.getParent()` in `pdialog = ProgressDialog.show(this.getParent(), "", "Retrieving Commissions...");`

Comment: That is `ActivityCommissions.this` instead of `this.getParent()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) for `ProgressDialog` 
a `Context` is what is needed to show the `ProgressDialog`.

See this

```
public static ProgressDialog show (Context context, CharSequence title, CharSequence message)
```

So,

Use your `Context` instead of `this.getParent()` in `pdialog = ProgressDialog.show(this.getParent(), "", "Retrieving Commissions...");`

That is

`ActivityCommissions.this` instead of `this.getParent()` in `pdialog = ProgressDialog.show(this.getParent(), "", "Retrieving Commissions...");`

So it should be like this

```
ProgressDialog.show(ActivityCommissions.this, "", "Retrieving Commissions...");
```

Comment: `this.getParent()` **does not** return a `ViewParent`

Comment: Why is this answer downvoted??? @ABFORCE getParent() returns a ViewParent..see the docs (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent.html#getParent())

Comment: 1. Type of `this` is `Activity` not `View`.  2.`this.getParent()` returns an object of type of `Activity`

Comment: dont know if its right..Any way i have removed that from my answer..Can you please remove that downvote..@ABFORCE

Comment: Please refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getParent()

Comment: Oh..Thankyou @ABFORCE..Thankyou very much..I was unaware about that..Again thankyou so much for the support...:)